# IE 9 flash loads but only half seen, IE flash does not load - every other browser works great

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Need some help.

Can someone look @ the source for this page http://qa.iorad.com/?a=app.player&accessCode=GUEST&remote=true&module=2054

It works great in all Webkit/Mozilla browers but in IE 9 we can only see the top half of the swf and in IE 8 it doesnt load @ all.

I searched all the other threads and nothing seems to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a form on the page? If so set its height to 100%.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
```

That is what fixed it happening on my side. Hope this helps.